# Highcharts error 13 in dynamic id

Tags: javascript, angularjs, highcharts

I have a DIV with id defined in a variable, in this DIV should be loaded a Highcharts graphic, however, when I define a variable ID it does not load but when I put a fixed ID it loads, when it does not load from ERROR 13 of the Highcharts (print this in console: Error: Highcharts error #13: www.highcharts.com/errors/13 ....).
How should I do to with Dynamic ID?

The DIV:

```
<div >
<div ng-attr-id="{{vm.chartModalClass}}" data-ng-init="vm.loadChart()" class="chart"></div>
</div>
```

The function in controller that generates the graph:

```
vm.chartModalClass = "chartPM";
vm.loadChart = loadChart;

function loadChart(){ 
    vm.chartPM = new Highcharts.chart(vm.chart);

};
```

How do I set the renderTo of the chart:

```
vm.chart = {
        chart: {
            type: 'column',
            renderTo: vm.chartModalClass,
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)'
        },....
```

Comment: post a fiddle with issue

Comment: Read [how to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and post a live example of the issue (jsfiddle/codepen/etc.)